# How DOW Index and a stock are correlated?

Tags: stock-analysis

The following is the chart of BA (Boeing) for 10/11/2021. In the chart, around 12:00 PM, the BA goes down. DOW Index goes down in relation to the BA move. All other stocks do down proportionately.

My questions are on what happened here:

1. Did the investors sell BA shares which brought down both BA as well as the DOW Index as a result?
2. Did the investors sell DOW Index funds (mutual or ETF) which brought down the Index and the BA too?
3. Is it possible that the price of BA will be up and same if the DOW Index goes up to the same level?
4. What technical indicator that I need to use to see the % of BA in the DOW Index?
5. What technical indicator that I need to use to see the % of impact of BA on the DOW Index or Vice Versa?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The DOW is a price-weighted index. Boeing makes up about [4%](https://www.indexarb.com/indexComponentWtsDJ.html) of the index, so any price movement in BA has a very minor effect on the index. It's more likely that the market as a whole was down due to some larger effect, and BA and the DOW were down because they are components of the market.
2. Index funds *track* the index, which is a computed number from its component stocks. Trading index funds does not directly affect the value of the index or the prices of the stocks within them.
3. I don't understand the question, but they can move independently (e.g. they can go in the same or opposite directions based on the movements of the other 96& of the index)
4. I don't know of a technical indicator, but the components and weights of the index are [published](https://www.indexarb.com/indexComponentWtsDJ.html).
5. The impact of the stock on the index is proportional to its weight. The index does not have an effect on its components (it is a calculation based on the prices of its components; it cannot be manipulated independent of them).

Comment: Re: *"Trading index funds does not affect the index or the stocks within them."* ... if you're referring to the *price* of the index, or the *price* of the stocks within them, then that part isn't true.

Comment: The index is calculated from the prices of its constituents and is not affected by trading of funds that _track_ the index. I left out that there _could_ be secondary effects if enough people buy/sell an index fund that the fund has to buy/sell the constituents to maintain tracking, but to my knowledge that effect is minimal.  If I'm missing something else please let me know.

Comment: @DStanley Is that really secondary? If I buy or sell 1 BA share, I won't move the price. If I buy or sell a million shares, surely the price will move. The same holds for ETF shares: if I buy a million ETF shares, a lot of them will be created eventually.

Comment: @glglgl If you buy a million ETF units, some will come from sellers, some will get created. The creation of those new units will probably result in the buying of constituent shares, which may have _some_ price movement as well. That's why I call it secondary. The buying results in some share creation, which results in some buying, which has some impact on constituent share price.

Comment: "but to my knowledge that effect is minimal." – I can't imagine why it would be. At least, I can't imagine why the effect would be _more_ minimal than the effect of buying individual stocks. Buying a Dow index fund is essentially the same as buying the component stocks, so if Boeing makes up about 4% of the Dow, then investing $1,000,000 in a Dow index fund should have the same effect as investing $40,000 in Boeing and $960,000 in the other components of the DJIA. Right?

Comment: @TannerSwett Not necessarily - if you buy units of that fund from someone else, there is zero impact on the component stocks. It's only when there's enough buying that the fund provider has to buy more underlying shares that it has an impact. Or when there's a significant difference between the ETF price and the index that participants buy underlying stocks to arbitrage profits and bring the index in line with the ETF price.

Comment: I guess I agree that buying an ETF doesn't have a *direct, immediate and instantaneous* effect on the price of the underlying stock, but I would expect that investing $1,000,000 in a Dow index fund would ultimately have the same impact as investing $1,000,000 in the underlying stocks, because for all practical purposes, investing $1,000,000 in a Dow index fund _is_ investing $1,000,000 in the underlying stocks.

Comment: For comparison, imagine a Boeing ETF, where one share of the ETF represents one share of Boeing. (Obviously such an ETF would probably never be created in real life, because it would be useless.) If Boeing's reported last trade price is $220.00, and I buy 100 shares of the ETF for $220.01, then the exchange will still report Boeing's last trade price as $220.00, not as $220.01. But in the long run, on average, buying shares of the ETF ought to exert exactly the same pressure on Boeing's stock as buying shares of the underlying stock.

Comment: @TannerSwett That's different than an index fund. An index fund just tracks the value of some index which is calculated from the prices of its underlying stocks. The fund doesn't _have_ to hold all of the underlying stocks to track the index. Some use futures or derivatives or other techniques to track the index. So buying the index is _not_ the same as buying the constituents, even in the long run. Buying the index means you _expect_ the index to go up, it does not directly affect the index itself (let alone the stocks that make up the index).

Comment: I think we've got different estimates of what the effect of arbitrage is. I think that thanks to arbitrage, on average, the effect of buying an ETF or a future (or any other derivative which replicates the underlying stock) equals 100% of the effect of buying the underlying stock itself. If I'm not mistaken, you think that the average effect is something less than 100%.